# Get data as list of tuple from dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, pandas-groupby

**Input data frame :**

```
    id    value
0    0     10.2
1    1      5.7
2    2      7.4
3    2      2.5
4    1      2.6
5    3      1.6
6    2      2.9
7    0      3.6
8    2      2.7
```

**Expected Output :**

```
format :   [(id,count_of_value,[value as a list])] i.e like this 
           [ (0,2,[10.2, 3.6]), (1, 2, [5.7, 2.6]). . ]
```

So far I am able to get the first two elements i.e id and it's count as a tuple, Also I needed the data in a reverse sorted order,

```
id_list = df.id.tolist()
count = Counter(uid_list)
ID_count_list = sorted(count.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
```

What is the most efficient way to get the value as explained in the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) to do it all in one step, matching the desired output:

```
result = df.groupby('id')['value'].apply(lambda x: (x.name, x.size, x.tolist())).tolist()
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[(0, 2, [10.2, 3.6]), (1, 2, [5.7, 2.6]), (2, 4, [7.4, 2.5, 2.9, 2.7]), (3, 1, [1.6])]
```

Given the output above you can sorted like this:

```
result = [(0, 2, [10.2, 3.6]), (1, 2, [5.7, 2.6]), (2, 4, [7.4, 2.5, 2.9, 2.7]), (3, 1, [1.6])]
s = sorted(result, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
print(s)
```

**Output** *(sorted)*

```
[(2, 4, [7.4, 2.5, 2.9, 2.7]), (0, 2, [10.2, 3.6]), (1, 2, [5.7, 2.6]), (3, 1, [1.6])]
```

Comment: Nice edit :). The only difference between our solutions is you create tuples in your `apply` (*possibly* less efficient, but probably also more readable).

Comment: Thanks @jpp! Do you know if agg is faster than apply? I'm just curious.

Comment: I'm not sure, to be honest, my *instinct* is `agg` since you aren't constructing a series of `tuples`, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @DanielMesejo : Thanks it worked, but I wanted data to be in sorted order

Comment: @DanielMesejo : Please check my question I wanted it to be sorted based max count

Comment: @csharpcoder You mean count_of_value, the second element in the tuple?

Comment: @DanielMesejo: Yes exactly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188003/discussion-between-csharpcoder-and-daniel-mesejo).

Answer (score 1):

This is a `groupby` problem. If a list of lists is sufficient:

```
res = df.groupby('id')['value'].agg(['count', lambda x: x.tolist()])\
        .reset_index().values.tolist()

print(res)

# [[0, 2, [10.2, 3.6]], [1, 2, [5.7, 2.6]],
#  [2, 4, [7.4, 2.5, 2.9, 2.7]], [3, 1, [1.6]]]
```

For a list of *tuples*, there's an additional step:

```
res = list(map(tuple, res))

print(res)

# [(0, 2, [10.2, 3.6]), (1, 2, [5.7, 2.6]),
#  (2, 4, [7.4, 2.5, 2.9, 2.7]), (3, 1, [1.6])]
```

Comment: You will be there today. Congratulations in anticipation.

Comment: @cph_sto, Thank you, just got there, now I'll take a break :)

Comment: `Member for 1 year` - very fast. wow ... now go to a good London bar and spoil yourself ... it's your day man.

Comment: You have piqued my curiosity for quite some time, so let me address it to you directly, if you allow me! - I remember the day when you hit 100K mark. It was 5th Feb. How come you put a blank full stop to answering any further Qs from that day onwards? Seems you put yourself a target, achived it and then quit for good. It does say something about your character - you come across as a person with immense self-control, discipline and fortitude, needless to say.